# How to deals with multiple equal weight in huffman code?

Tags: huffman-code

I want to create a Huffman Tree with the following frequency for each element:
A - 32
B - 15
C - 0
D - 11
E - 11
F - 11
G - 0
H - 0
I - 0
J - 0
K - 0

[This lecture](http://cs.gettysburg.edu/~skim/cs216/lectures/huffman.pdf) I've found online uses alphabetical order. But when using this [Huffman Tree generator site](http://planetcalc.com/2481/) it doesn't seem like using an alphabetical order. What logic behind these decision to match those with 0 weight?(or multiple nodes with same weight).

Answer (score 0):

Zero weight symbols are not coded at all, so they do not enter into the discussion.

Equal weight symbols are not really the relevant thing to look at.  What you look at are equal bit length codes.  Codes of the same bit length are ordered by symbol (e.g. "alphabetically") in order to reduce the size of the Huffman code representation for the purpose of transmitting that representation along with the data.  See [Canonical Huffman Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code).